# How do I prove $\mathscr{B}$ is a countable basis for the topology of $\hat U$ in Lemma 1.10 of Lee's Introduction to smooth manifolds?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

This is **Lemma 1.10** in **Introduction to smooth manifolds by John Lee**, 2nd edition.

> **Lemma 1.10. Every topological manifold has a countable basis of precompact coordinate balls.**
>
> **Proof**. Let $M$ be a topological $n$-manifold. First we consider the special case in which $M$ can be covered by a single chart.
> Suppose $\varphi: M \to \hat U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a global
> coordinate map, and let $\mathscr{B}$ be the collection of all open
> balls $B_r(x)\subseteq  \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $r$ is rational, $x$
> has rational coordinates, and $B_{r'}(x)\subseteq  \hat U$ for some
> $r' > r$. Each such ball is precompact in $\hat U$, and **it is easy
> to check that $\mathscr{B}$ is a countable basis for the topology of
> $\hat U$**. Because $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism, it follows that
> the collection of sets of the form $ \varphi^{-1}(B)$ for$ B \in \mathscr{B}$ is a countable basis for the topology of $M$;
> consisting of precompact coordinate balls, with the restrictions of
> $\varphi$ as coordinate maps.

The author says it is easy but I don't know how to write it down. My question is mainly about proving that $\mathscr{B}$ is a basis,not about the countability part. I guess if I can prove it is a basis, then the countability part it's an standard procedure.  According to the text,

$\mathscr{B} = \{ B_r(x) :B_r(x) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n, r \in \mathbb{Q}_{>0}, x \in \mathbb{Q}^n; \forall r \in \mathbb{Q}_{>0}, \exists r'>r \text{ such that} B_{r'}(x)\subseteq \hat U \}$.

Since $\mathscr{B}$ is made out of open sets, I  think I have to prove that for any set $A \in \tau_{\hat U}$, $A=\bigcup_{i \in I, B_i \in \mathscr{B} }B_i$.

Additionally, since $A\in \tau_{\hat U}$, then it must be of the form $A=\hat U \cap U$, with $U \in \tau_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ and $U = \bigcup_{j \in J, B_j \in \tau_{\mathbb{R}^n}}B_j$. How do I continue for here?, if this is useful at all.  Furthermore I am specially clued about how to deal with the the last condition in the definition of$\mathscr{B}$ (that is  that $\forall r \in \mathbb{Q}_{>0}, \exists r'>r \text{ such that} B_{r'}(x)\subseteq \hat U $ ), since this seems to restrict the open sets inside $\hat U$ to only those that admit some other ball WHICH IS ALSO IN $\hat  U$ at the same center with a bigger radius; so, what if I needed those left-off balls to express some $A\in \tau_{\hat U}$ as a union of open sets?

Thank you!

Comment: $\Bbb{Q}^n\times\Bbb{Q}$ is countable.  More than that is trouble.

Comment: @ Bob Dobbs What do you mean with trouble?